# Is there any way to send Pull Requests and / or Merge PRs on GitHub using Google Colab?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I couldn't find if this option was available in to use directly from Google Colab anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, Colab does not accept pull requests as described here:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools#contributing

[image]